# How to convert a big decimal number in a String into Hexadecimal in Java?

Tags: java, hex

i have 12 digit number in a string, I need to convert it to hexadecimal.

```
unit_address = '0064627520128';
```

I tried using

```
Integer.toHexString("string")
```

but it doesn't work as the decimal value is big.

Only integer values are possible to convert to hex using this but not in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use BigInteger instead of BigDecimal. This way you could use

`new BigInteger("18446744073709551616").toString(16)`

If you can't change type of original object convert it to BigInteger later in method

`new BigDecimal("18446744073709551616").toBigInteger().toString(16);`

Comment: @DebashisPanda Please provide an example of the input you expect, the output you expect, and the different output you get, that is as small as possible.